# Express API via Heroku server sends set-cookie header however the cookie is not set. Works fine on postman and localhost server but not Heroku server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have been trying to send authentication token for my project via Cookies. This seemed to work fine when I was working with my localhost server. However when I deployed my project on Heroku, i was unable to receive any cookie in my browser.
NOTE: I was able to receive cookies in postman (from both Heroku and Localhost).

Below is the code for the creating the cookie in my sign-in API

```
res.cookie('token', token,{
  maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: 'none',
  secure: true, 
})
```

I am have also used the following code for enabling CORS.

```
const corsConfig = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsConfig));
```

I have also enabled "trust proxy" since i came threads where developers suggested using it for heroku.

```
app.enable("trust proxy");
```

The browser receives set-cookie header from the response however it does not set the cookie when i switch to my heroku server. Which i checked from Network tab in inspect element. However no cookie is set when i view the Application tab in inspect element.

Comment: Does the browser console contain messages about third-party cookies being blocked?

Comment: Nope. There is no error or message on the browser regarding third-party cookies or cookies in general